# How common is it to use "шобы" instead of "чтобы"? And how to use it?

Tags: словоупотребление

> У нас должна быть ясная голова, **шобы** делать свою работу, да?

I gather it is equivalent to "чтобы", given the context and that "шо" seems to be a distorted form of "что", possibly of Ukrainian origin.

Comment: We pronounce "штобы".

Comment: @V.V. At least, pronunciation-wise, are these two identical?

Comment: I believe it's regional,  highly colloquial,  the meaning is the same, but it would be weird if you try to use "шо" instead of "што ".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in meaning **шобы = чтобы** (and their respective shortened forms **шоб = чтоб**)

I don't think this pertains to pronunciation in Russian Federation, in Ukraine however in informal loose speech it's very widespread, but still belongs to low register, which nobody seems to feel uncomfortable with.

Could be influenced by a native Ukrainian counterpart **щоб(и) [щоб(ы)]**

I would not recommend using it at all, as it's a regionalism which must be accompanied with other regional features to sound authentic, if nothing else (not to speak of euphony, which it lacks). Otherwise it will sound out of place.